# Solving complex Exponential equations problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation

How can we solve an equation like this:
      $$3^{2x+1} +9= 3^{x+3} +3^x$$
i.e $3$ raised to the power $2x+2$ plus $9$ equals $3$ raised to the power $x+3$, plus $3$ raised to the power $x$.

Comment: Let $y=3^x$ then you basically have $3y^2+9=27y+y$, which is a quadratic. Solve it for $y$ then sub in $y=3^x$ and use logarithms.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's Seems interesting, but please how do we manage to have 27y

Comment: because $3^{x+3}=3^x\times 3^3=27\cdot3^x=27y$.

Comment: Wow, Thank you sir.  Sir , please the  3y^2 + 9 = 27y + y, crossing the equal sign , 27y + y,  would change to -27y -  y?  i.e To bring to quadratic equation

Comment: Yes that's correct, then you just solve it like a quadratic. You will end up with some solution. You will then need to solve for $x$ which will involve logarithms I think.

Comment: Thank you sir, I think I can try for quadratic equation but the logarithm part might be very challenging . Please help.                            a=3, b=-28, c=-9.
x=
−b±√b2−4ac
2a
x=
−(−28)±√(−28)2−4(3)(−9)
2(3)
x=
28±√892
6
x=
14
3
+
1
3
√223 or x=
14
3
+
−1
3
√223
Answer:
x=
14
3
+
1
3
√223 or x=
14
3
+
−1
3
√223

Comment: $c=9$ not $-9$.

Comment: Ok sir, that's cool. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all terms on one side, you get
$$
0 = 3^{2x+1} +9 - 3^{x+3} +3^x
  = 3 \cdot \left(3^x\right)^2 + 9 - 3^3 3^x + 3^x
  = 3u^2+9-27u+u,
$$
where $u=3^x$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you sir, I think I can try it now